# How To Output ObjectsToCsv with a delimiter not ,

Tags: node.js, express

Trying to use MySQL and Node/Express to output a CSV
The output works but the default delimeter is a comma. I am trying to get the delimeter to be ^^

Hopefully this code can be adjusted and im just missing a parameter or something

I need the output delimiter to be ^^ here is whatI have so far..

```
  var express = require('express');
    var router = express.Router();
    fs = require('fs');
    var mysql = require('mysql');
    var csvParser = require('csv-parse');
    const ObjectsToCsv = require('objects-to-csv');
    router.post('/', function(req, res, next) {
      
      
          var con = mysql.createConnection({
            host: "localhost",
            user: "root",
            password: "root",
            database: "library"
        });
        const keys = Object.keys(req.body)
        console.log(keys[0]);
        console.log('let start')
        //codebase
        let tableName='testimport'
        con.query(`SELECT * FROM ${tableName} WHERE filename='${keys[0]}'`, function (err, result, fields) {
            (async () => {
       
                new ObjectsToCsv(result).toDisk('./test.csv', { allColumns: true, delimiter:'^^' });
               
                await csv.toDisk('./ResponseOutput.csv', { delimiter: '^^' });
                //change headers
               
            })();
        });
        //codebaseEND
        res.send('exporting..')
    })
    
    
    module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Hold up, you are using the unsanitized request body directly inside your sql query. This can lead to sql injection. Use a library like sqlstring to sanitize your sql before you make the query.

Comment: Thanks, its running on a wamp local and will never see the light of day and im the only user. this is just to make a daily task easier on my end but i do appreciate the comment on standard practice

Answer (score 1):

I could not find the delimiter option for `toDisk` in the `objects-to-csv` package. I used `fast-csv` to create the csv with a custom delimiter:

```js
const fastCsv = require('fast-csv');
const fs = require('fs');
const keys = ['firstName', 'lastName', 'city'];
const delimiter = '^^';

const data = [
  {
    firstName: 'Andy',
    lastName: 'Cole',
    city: 'Berlin',
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Anna',
    lastName: 'Kendrick',
    city: 'New York'
  },
  {
    firstName: 'Jason',
    lastName: 'Bourne',
    city: 'Paris'
  }
];

const stream = fastCsv.format({ delimiter: '^^' });
const writeStream = fs.createWriteStream('./output.csv');
stream.pipe(writeStream);

for (const row of data) {
  stream.write(row);
}

stream.end();
```

You create a stream that reads an object and converts it to a row of csv data. To write this data to a file, we pipe it to writeable file stream.